# Drupal 6 Webform - Component rendered in wrong position

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm adding a new component to a Drupal 6 webform. New 'select options' components are all rendered in the same area, no matter which position they are given in the backend. I've just added 'Area of Interest' as a listbox and as the first item of the webform. Check out where it ends up: [removed]

The site was set up by another development team so I'm not sure what the heck they did to Webform. Anyone know what they could have done? I'm going to have to recreate the webform from scratch otherwise.

Pic of my setup screen:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the html that your webform is outputting, it starts to make more sense.

The 'city' and 'area of interest' fields are both children of the 'webform-component-city' div, so they appear side-by-side.  It's hard to figure out why this is happening without having access to your webform, but I hope it helps you in troubleshooting the issue further.

[image]

If you don't have firebug or other web dev tools installed on your browser to help you look at the html of your website, you still may be able to troubleshoot by just viewing the source on your webform....

Let us know if you have any other questions or if you figure it out!

Comment: Thanks for the help - should have mentioned that I did see this, and I'm still not sure what the heck is going on. Posted a picture of my settings page in the OP.

Comment: And have you tried just deleting the field and re-creating it again (the 'Area of Interest' one)?  And re-creating it without cloning another field, but just from scratch?

Comment: Yup, I recreated another webform entirely, and that one is simply not displaying the Country and State selectboxes. Something is rendering the selectboxes in some insane way, but the script isn't in template.php nor in the webform module. Kind of stuck here.

Comment: Hey, one more question: are you using the latest version of the module?  If not, I'd try upgrading (backup code and db, in case you need to roll back) to see if that resolves your bug.

Comment: Yeah, I just did and it's still having problems. I'm going to set up a new Drupal instance with the theme I'm using and webform and see if I can recreate it. If I can, would you be interested in taking a look at the internals?

Comment: Sure.  Let me know what you find, and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: Thanks for all the help - turns out the layout switching was occurring in a Javascript file that I had mistaken for a plugin file due to naming.